# How to search and replace function for "vscode vim"?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

**i have tried but didnot find a way to search and replace in vscode with the vim keybindings plugin. The vim console doesn't take regular vims search and replace function `:5,9s/foo/bar/g` and vscode's default Ctrl+f doesn't work either as it is a vim binding.**

Comment: I am using this vim plugin: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to use VSCode's default search functionality while using the Vim extension, you need to configure the extension .

```
"vim.handleKeys": { "<C-f>": false }
```

Check [the documentation](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#vscodevim-settings) for more information.

Regarding the actual vim search functionality, I cannot confirm it not working. The example you provided works on my end.

Input:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Running `:5,9s/foo/bar/g` results in:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
bar
bar
bar
bar
bar
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 4):

I have VSCode with Vim, and for me `Ctrl+Shift+H` works equivalent to `Ctrl+F` without Vim. For returning back to the file, press `Ctrl+Tab`.

Answer (score 2):

The extension "vscodevim" v1.21.10 does support regular vim search and replace functions such as:

```
:%s/"/'/g
```

Comment: thx mate, this one worked, :s/"/'/g didn't

Answer (score 0):

In VSCodeVim, many Ex-commands require [Neovim integration](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#neovim-integration).

**Setup**:

1. Install [Neovim](https://neovim.io/)
2. Enable Neovim via `vim.enableNeovim`
3. Set the Neovim path via `vim.neovimPath`